# Communicating with Docker Service through Published Port

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm trying to run multiple instances of a Docker image on a single node and send requests to the node allowing Docker to load balance between the instances.

If I use the **Run** command shown below the container behaves as expected, I can send a request from another machine on port 80 and the request is serviced by container. However, if I try to spin up a service with the **Service** command shown below I do get 5 replicated tasks running but the request only returns a 404 error.

How can I communicate with the service through my exposed port?

This sample includes a ASP.Net Core 2.0 api that returns a Guid unique to the instance of the app.

**Controller**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;

namespace MinimalDockerTest.Controllers {
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class NodeController : Controller {

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get() {
            return Ok(NodeId);
        }

        private static Guid NodeId {
            get;
        } = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
#Context is binary output folder, i.e. bin/publishoutput
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0-nanoserver-sac2016
EXPOSE 80
WORKDIR /app
Copy . .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MinimalDockerTest.dll"]
```

**Build Command**

```
docker build -t minimaltest .
```

**Run Command**

```
docker run -p 80:80 --name minimaltest minimaltest
```

**Service Command**

```
docker service create -p 80:80 --replicas 5 --name minimaltest minimaltest
```

**Request**

```
GET: http://node_ip/api/node
```

**System**

- Windows 10 1703 Build 15063.0
- Docker CE 17.12.0-ce-win46 (15048)

**Edit**

Found some good info here on SO.

> I beleive you need to publish port in "host" mode (learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/…‌​). Also it will be one to one port mapping between running container and host and hence you will not be able to run several containers on the same port. **Routing mesh is not working on Windows yet.**

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44371945/7339946)

Now the question remains; When will mesh routing be supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently mesh routing is not available for Windows 10 Version 1703. Mesh Routing was made the default option on Windows with version 1709.

[Box Boat](https://boxboat.com/2017/11/08/docker-windows-server-1709/)

[MS Blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2017/09/26/dockers-ingress-routing-mesh-available-with-windows-server-version-1709/)

[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44371945/7339946)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aren't pulling a different image from the registry. By default, `docker service` will resolve the image name from the registry so that it will work on multiple nodes in the cluster. While `docker run` will use the image as it exists on the local node. You can disable this resolution process with the `--no-resolve-image` option:

```
docker service create -p 80:80 --replicas 5 --name minimaltest \
  --no-resolve-image minimaltest
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can see that the correct image, minimaltest:latest, is used for each of the 5 replicas and all are listening on port 80. When I try to make the api call all I get is a 404. If I publish the port with `mode=host` and let Docker wire up a random port I can make request to that port from an external machine and get success response. Any idea what might cause the 404?

Comment: The 404 means you reached your app and your app didn't like the request. This is probably getting into a dotnet question which is out of my scope.